# Ties - is there a distinction between these two notes?

Tags: notation, ties

How would you play this? I think I generally understand how ties work but I'm a bit confused by the marked articulation. Would you hear a distinction between the two notes?

[image]

Comment: Instrument? Context? Piece? other voices?

Comment: ...and rest of the measure. Is it 6/8 by chance?

Answer (score 2):

The tenuto mark is there to inform the player that the curve connecting the two notes is not a tie but a slur -- a bowing mark.  This is two notes to be played without reversing the direction in which the bow is traveling.

Comment: No pitch change and the bow direction doesn't change, but there would be some articulation, right? How might that be done?

Answer (score 0):

In a piece for piano such a tied note with a tenuto sign  doesn’t make much sense. Wood wind -, Brass- and String instrument could interprete this as legato and added tenuto eighth note: da-a-a daat.

But I assume this bow is not a tie but a phrasing bow.

Answer (score 0):

The tenuto bar concerns how long you hold the complete note.  It does not affect the tie.  However, here are several indications that this is not actually a tie: first ties are usually much flatter and shorter.  Second, it would be rather unusual to split a half note up in that manner unless the second of the tied notes falls on a strong subdivision of the measure (there is too little shown to know whether this is the case).

On instruments where the slur indicates some detail of technical execution, like on a bowed string instrument ("don't reverse bow direction"), a tenuto bar may indicate detachment, but only so if it is placed on the *first* of the tied notes.  If that is done, most commonly the second of the tied notes also gets a tenuto bar when equal articulation of both notes is desired.

As written, and assuming a tie rather than a slur, the tenuto bar indicates how a note of four eighths of length is supposed to be articulated at its end.